# IDE0055 Fix formatting

Tags: c#, formatting

I'm getting the error IDE0055 in the file. Can someone help me out?

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Module.Tests")]
```

Comment: Is there any additional information regarding this warning in your IDE? VS has a QuickFix option

Comment: Can you please try following code: [assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo("Module.Tests")]

Comment: That's the only error I get on the file. The only quick fix is fix formatting and it doesn't work.

Comment: It's still not working with the code.